# Additional increment after exiting for loop

Tags: javascript

Why does the following code increment the variable age to 11 after the for loop has already completed. I understand that let has block scope and that if I initialize age in the loop using let it the console log outside the loop will print 15. However, why does age get incremented to 11 when it the tests in the loop stop incrementing when age is 10?

```
var age = 15;

// for loop that prints age initialized at 1 
// loop finsishes when age is 10 and logs 10
for (var age = 1; age <= 10; age++) {
  console.log(age);
}

// following log increments age to 11
console.log(age);
```

Comment: The loop fails when age is 11 and thus comes out and since you have already declared the variable before the loop thus I think its taking the same one in the for loop too so there is only one `age` variable all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition is to stop incrementing when `age` is more than `10` because you have use `<=` and not `<`. So only when `age` reaches `11` via `age++`, you can exit the loop.

Answer (score 1):

As it stated [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) for the final-expression:

```
for ([initialization]; [condition]; [final-expression])
   statement
```

> An expression to be evaluated at the end of each loop iteration. This
> occurs before the next evaluation of condition. Generally used to
> update or increment the counter variable.

So the last time `age` becomes 10, it is increased once more in the final expression, and then the condition is evaluated again. Since now `age` is 11, the condition evaluates to false and loop execution stops.